# How to randomly create a maze

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, maze

I currently have code that opens up all of the doors on my prefabs for rooms/tiles that are not on the edges of my randomly generated map. I would like to modify this code so that not all of the doors are open and it is more of a randomly generated maze. I want every room to be accessible and it is possible to have more than one path through the maze/game world. How can I change my code so it works in this manner? Below is my current code that I want to modify.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Room : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject doorNorth;
    public GameObject doorSouth;
    public GameObject doorEast;
    public GameObject doorWest;
}

using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class mapGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public GameObject[] gridPrefabs;
    private float roomWidth = 50.0f;
    private float roomHeight = 50.0f;
    public Room[,] grid;//used to keep track of rooms created ,uses two numbers to refer to it in memory
    public bool isMapOfDay;
    public bool isRandomMap;
    public int chosenSeed;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        chosenSeed = GameManager.instance.mapSeed;
        rows = GameManager.instance.mapRows;
        cols = GameManager.instance.mapColumns;
        isMapOfDay = GameManager.instance.useMapOfDay;
        isRandomMap = GameManager.instance.useRandomMap;
        gridPrefabs = GameManager.instance.mapTiles;

    }


    public GameObject RandomRoomPrefab()//Returns a random room
    {   
        return gridPrefabs [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, gridPrefabs.Length)];      
    }
    public void GenerateGrid()//used to generate map grid
    {

        if (isRandomMap == true && isMapOfDay == false) {//sets map to random map based on time
            UnityEngine.Random.InitState(DateToInt(DateTime.Now));//sets "random" seed to current time
        } else if (isRandomMap == false && isMapOfDay == true) {//sets map to map of day based on numbers in day
            UnityEngine.Random.InitState(DateToInt (DateTime.Now.Date));
        } else {//if both are selected just use random map
            UnityEngine.Random.InitState(DateToInt (DateTime.Now));
        }
        if (chosenSeed != 0) {//if a specific seed is entered in game manager use this instead
            UnityEngine.Random.InitState(chosenSeed);
        }
        //Clear out the grid
        grid = new Room[cols, rows];
        GameManager.instance.mapGrid = grid;
        //For each grid row...
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            //for each column in that row
            for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) 
            {
                //Figure out the location
                float xPosition = roomWidth * j;
                float zPosition = roomHeight * i;
                Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (xPosition, 0.0f, zPosition);
                //create a new grid at appropiate location
                GameObject tempRoomObj = Instantiate (RandomRoomPrefab (), newPosition, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
                //set its parent
                tempRoomObj.transform.parent = this.transform;
                //give the temp room a meaningful name
                tempRoomObj.name = "Room_" + j + "," + i;
                //Get the room object
                Room tempRoom = tempRoomObj.GetComponent<Room> ();
                //open doors as needed
                if (i == 0) {
                    //open north doors if on bottom row
                    tempRoom.doorNorth.SetActive (false);
                } else if (i == rows - 1) {
                    //Otherwise, if doors are on the top row open south doors
                    tempRoom.doorSouth.SetActive (false);
                } else {
                    //otherwise, this row is in the middle so both north and south open
                    tempRoom.doorNorth.SetActive (false);
                    tempRoom.doorSouth.SetActive (false);
                }
                if (j == 0) {
                    //if first column then east doors are opened
                    tempRoom.doorEast.SetActive (false);
                } else if (j == cols - 1) {
                    //Otheriwse, if one last column row open west doors
                    tempRoom.doorWest.SetActive (false);
                } else {
                    //otherwise, we are in middle so both west and east are opened
                    tempRoom.doorEast.SetActive (false);
                    tempRoom.doorWest.SetActive (false);
                }

                //save it to the grid array
                grid [j, i] = tempRoom;//
                GameManager.instance.mapGrid=grid;
            }
        }

    }
    public int DateToInt(DateTime dateToUse)//adds date and time up and returns it as an int
    {
        int dateToReturn = dateToUse.Year + dateToUse.Month + dateToUse.Day + dateToUse.Hour +dateToUse.Minute + dateToUse.Second + dateToUse.Millisecond;
        return dateToReturn;
    }
    public void clear()//clears grid
    {
        for (int c=0; c<GameManager.instance.mapGrid.GetLength(0); c++) {
            for (int r=0; r<GameManager.instance.mapGrid.GetLength(1); r++) {
                if(GameManager.instance.mapGrid[c,r]!=null)//if not null destroy
                {
                   Destroy(GameManager.instance.mapGrid[c,r].gameObject);
                }


            }

        }
    }

}
```

I believe the change needs to happen in my else statements but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this as I have never made a maze before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog, it maybe can help you to understand of procedural generation of mazes in Unity.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/82-procedural-generation-of-mazes-with-unity

But in essence you can use Recursive backtracker algorithm. It's relative simple to implement.

Mark your startpoint as visited & choose a random neightbor which is unvisited.

Randomly choose a grid at that starting point and carve a passage through to the near grid(only if the near grid has not been visited yet. It'll be the new grid

Return to the last grid that has uncarved wall and repeat, only if all near grids have been in visited state.

The algorithm ends when the process has backed all the way up to the starting point.

I hope you could clarify a little more about what you are looking for.